# глобальная передача нажатия клавиш в активное окно

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Всем привет. подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли простой способ имитировать нажатия клавиш в активном окне, при свернутой программе(использую WPF)? пробовал через autoIt, но работает через раз.
или все же придется копаться в WinAPI?

```
public void Horisonter(string value, int speed = 10, int latency = 100)
{
    Point horisontPosition = Inventory.horisontPoint;
    List<Point> pointsOfInventory = HorisontOrb.points;

    AutoItX.WinActivate("Path of Exile");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    AutoItX.MouseMove((int)horisontPosition.X, (int)horisontPosition.Y, speed);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(latency);

    AutoItX.MouseClick("right");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

    AutoItX.Send("{SHIFTDOWN}");

    string allMapList = string.Empty;
    string IsContainValue = string.Empty;

    string mapCurrent = string.Empty;


    int counts = 0;
    int countsInside = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        AutoItX.MouseMove((int)pointsOfInventory[i].X, (int)pointsOfInventory[i].Y, speed);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(latency); //задержка сервера


        AutoItX.Send("^c");


        mapCurrent = Clipboard.GetText();

        if (mapCurrent == "asd")
            goto EndHorisonting;

        if (currKeysPressed.Contains("Escape") || currKeysPressed.Contains("Subtract"))
        {
            currKeysPressed = string.Empty;
            goto EndHorisonting;
        }

        if (mapCurrent.Contains(value))
        {
            AutoItX.ClipPut("asd");
            mapCurrent = "";
            continue;
        }
        while (!mapCurrent.Contains(value))
        {
            AutoItX.MouseClick("left");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(latency); //задержка сервера                    

            AutoItX.Send("^c");

            mapCurrent = AutoItX.ClipGet();

            if (mapCurrent.Contains(value))
            {
                AutoItX.ClipPut("asd");
                countsInside++;
                break;
            }

            if (currKeysPressed.Contains("Escape") || currKeysPressed.Contains("Subtract"))
            {
                currKeysPressed = string.Empty;
                goto EndHorisonting;
            }
        }
        counts++;
    }

    EndHorisonting:;

    AutoItX.Send("{SHIFTUP}");
    MessageBox.Show($"counts={counts.ToString()}\n\n countsinside={countsInside.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: Свернутой игре или WPF приложении? Что именно работает через раз, как вы это поняли?

Comment: Win API - это метод `SendInput`, и под него уже есть хорошая готовая шарповая библиотека SendInput в NuGet. Но оно подходит только для активного приложения. Второй подходящий метод - `SendMessage`, он отправляет приложениям Windows сообщения, которые обрабатываются через Message Loop (например Winforms, WPF, C++ Native window). С DirectX играми и это не работает, потому что там нет Message Loop.

Comment: @aepot свернутое wpf.  понял, что работает через раз, когда выполняю итерацию одного цикла 10 раз. а результаты разные с каждым запуском. иногда делается без ошибок, иногда срабатывает тригер на выход цикла(когда не должен), иногда не выполняются условия проверки. хотя я не совсем понимаю, как один и тот же кусок кода может выполнятся и не выполниться в следующий раз.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в блокировке потока, где у вас выполняется код, поток надо отпускать чтобы сообщения нормально проходили по системе. Наверняка `Thread.Sleep` делаете.

Comment: @aepot да, можете подробней, пожалуйста?

Comment: Поподробней без кода в вопросе сказать не могу, я же не телепат. Если я прав, то ваше "через раз" заработает нормально, если запустить ваше приложение с отключенным UAC в системе или от имени Администратора.

Comment: @aepot заранее прошу прощения за код. я использовал разные методы "доставания" данных из буфера. думал в этом проблема. https://pastebin.com/B7WUXy01

Comment: Код надо вставить прямо в пост текстом, вы можете его редактировать.

Comment: @aepot от админа запускал - ничего не помогло. сейчас ищу инфу о winAPI.но стаж у меня, мягко говоря, не очень большой для таких дел. поэтому искал варианты попроще.

Comment: Попробуйте так `public async void Horisonter` и везде вместо `Thread.Sleep` используйте `await Task.Delay`. В самом начале кода добавьте `using System.Threading.Tasks;`. Кстати, вы же не в отдельном потоке этот код запускаете, надеюсь?

Comment: если честно, даже не знаю как сделать отдельный поток. завтра попробую обновить код. спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Про шарповую библиотеку опечатался выше в комментарии, InputSimulator она называется в NuGet пакетах.